# adding RichFaces breaks my JSF project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf, richfaces

I have a simple JSF project which works just fine; after adding RichFaces to it, it stops working properly

**Environment**: Eclipse IDE, JSF 2.1 (Apache MyFaces 2.1.5), Tomcat v7.0 Server (Location: workspace metadata, Server Locations: Use Tomcat installation); http://localhost:8181/ gives me the admin console, so the server is running ok

**The application**: a Dynamic Web Project (version 3.0) named *jsf1*;

under WebContent, i have a page named main.xhtml (For brevity, i won't paste the content, because things work well so far; Its a simple hello world page);

the faces-config.xml is left unchanged;

the web.xml contains:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In Project Explorer, i right click on the project > Run As > Run on Server, and  the application is accessible in a web browser at the url http://localhost:8181/jsf1/faces/main.xhtml

**Adding RichFaces**: i followed the instructions given at https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html

under  WEB-INF/lib  i have added all the required jars[image]

i have appended to web.xml the following content:

```
<!-- Plugging the "Blue Sky" skin into the project -->
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
   <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->
<context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
      <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->
<filter> 
   <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name> 
   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 
   <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, when i run the project on server, in the console i get:

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter richfaces
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter

I added the richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar, which contains the org.ajax4jsf.Filter class. 
Now, when i run the project on server,the console contains no errors, however, the link http://localhost:8181/jsf1/faces/main.xhtml displays a blank page.

How is it possible to create a functional RichFaces application?

Comment: I see you are already using PrimeFaces 3.5, may I ask why you want to start adding RichFaces? Mixing these might result in several more problems...

Comment: i will remove primefaces; i just needed it because i used some primefaces tag, but i dont need it anymore

Comment: SURE???? Start reading here: http://richfaces.jboss.org/ So instead of extending the usage of a well supported, active, modern jsf component suite (PrimeFaces) you want to start using the predecessor or RichFaces 4 which by itself is EOL.... Really sure?

Comment: i just didn't know that! thanks for pointing that out! to me, both frameworks seemed equally viable options. Anyway, i still have to use RichFaces, its part of the stack at my workplace

Comment: On your classpath you have both RF 4.5.17 and 3.3.3. This doesn't seem to be right. You can't use both. Also, RF 3 is really old and was design in time of JSF 1.X. I'd start with reading this: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20